# Lyapunov Condition for bounded random variables

Tags: probability

I found the following excercise:. It is an excercie from Billingsley Probability and measure: suppose $(X_{nk})$,  $k=1,\ldots,r_n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ satisfy $|X_{nk}|<K_n$ and $K_n=o(s_n)$, where $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^{r_n} E|X_{nk}|^2$. Show the Lyapunov Condition, i.e. there is some $\delta>0$ such that
$$\frac{1}{s_n^{2+\delta}}\sum_{k=1}^{r_n}E|X_{nk}|^{2+\delta}\to 0.$$

Naive estimation does not achieve anything. The first thing which is not clear to me is the following: $K_n=o(s_n)$ is satisfied if $M_n$ goes to zero and $s_n\to s<\infty$. But in this case the Lindeberg condition has not to be fulfilled and so the Lypaunov condition neither. So I suppose the statment is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Since $|X_{nk}|\leqslant K_n$ almost surely, $|X_{nk}|^{2+\delta}\leqslant K_n^\delta|X_{nk}|^2$ almost surely, hence
$$\frac{1}{s_n^{2+\delta}}\sum_{k=1}^{r_n}E|X_{nk}|^{2+\delta}\leqslant\frac{1}{s_n^{2+\delta}}\sum_{k=1}^{r_n}K_n^\delta E|X_{nk}|^{2}=\left(\frac{K_n}{s_n}\right)^\delta.$$ Thus, Lyapunov condition holds for every $\delta\gt0$.